# Show more logs in kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am using the [official kubernetes dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) in Version `kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.4.0` to manage my cluster and I've noticed that, when I select a pod and look into the logs, the length of the displayed logs is quite short. It's like 50 lines or something?

If an exception occurs, the logs are pretty much useless because the original cause is hidden by lots of other lines. I would have to download the logs or shell to the kubernetes server and use `kubectl logs` in order to see whats going on.

Is there any way to configure the dashboard in a way so that more lines of logs get displayed?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible with `kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.4.0`. On the [list of dashboard arguments](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/common/dashboard-arguments.md) that allow for customization, there is no option to change the amount of logs displayed.

As a workaround you can use [Prometheus + Grafana](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/) combination or [ELK kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana/) as separate dashboards with logs/metrics, however depending on the size and scope of your k8s cluster it might be overkill. There are also alternative k8s opensource dashboards such as [skooner](https://github.com/skooner-k8s/skooner) (formerly known as k8dash), however I am not sure if it offers more workload logs visibility.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i have added a feature request in github, maybe they consider it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested: As the feature that i was looking for does not exist yet, i have submitted a feature request in GitHub. You can see it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/6700